# Speed up OpenCV video decoding and encoding

Tags: opencv

How can I speed up video encoding (VideoWriter) and decoding (VideoCapture) in opencv? Can I use TBB (threading building blocks) library?

I am working with 1280x720 (720p) video and developing a real-time system but my video frame reading and writing alone are consuming 35 ms per frame. Please help.

Comment: Good question.. As workaround, maybe you can lower the resolution?

Comment: afaik writing and reading both runs already in an independent thread. Try to test how big the effect from each of that is (it might be just a slow camera)

Comment: I am detecting features and tracking them in order to estimate the motion between frames...so decreasing the resolution would not be a good idea...as incorrectly computed motion will show vividly on such large image size.......

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz....I am reading video from a file...not camera....video is 30 FPS